# config.xml for custom email template

Tags: email, configuration, xml, transactional-mail

For some odd reason `<email> </email>` breaks my page in `system > transactional emails`.

```
<template>
    <email>
        <notification_tpl module="Notification">
            <label>Product Notification</label>
            <file>Notification.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </notification_tpl>
    </email>
</template>
```

The only thing that loads is the template drop-down at the top and it no longer functions and the rest of the page below it is broken.

I noticed when i delete `<email> </email>` and leave the rest the page builds it's self proper like again.

Answer (score 2):

i think problem with your module name `module="Notification"`

change it to `module="notification"`.

@fschmengler mention..

Explanation: This is used to determine the helper for translation, and if `Mage::helper('Notification')` returns nothing, it breaks with a 
**cannot call __ on null**
 error.

Comment: Explanation: This is used to determine the helper for translation, and if `Mage::helper('Notification')` returns nothing, it breaks with a "cannot call __ on null" error.

Comment: Why are you telling me this? I agree with you, just wanted to add some explanation *why* it is wrong ;-)